# Retract solution in sharepoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010

How to retract a sharepoint solution without having remaining list intances, workflows, data etc?

never seen this kind of scenario.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would need to be designed into the solution itself, namely the feature(s) used to deploy its content.  You would need to manually (because sharepoint doesn't by default) delete the lists created in the solution, pause/delete the workflows started, remove content types, and so on.

I understand this to be a conscious decision.  It would be too risky for Microsoft to have someone blame them for the loss of a lot of extremely valuable data just because they retracted a code solution.